# WPF ComboBox не обновляет Text когда IsEditable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `ComboBox`, проблем в том что когда он `IsEditable="True"` не работает обновление текста при изменении его в записи, если убрать то все работает. Почему?

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="35" Height="35" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"/>
    </DockPanel> 
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged {
private ObservableCollection<Record> _records;
public ObservableCollection<Record> Records {
  get => this._records;
  set {
    this._records = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Records));
  }
}

public MainViewModel() {
  this.Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
  this.Records.Add(new Record() {
    Name = "Test"
  });
  this.Records.Add(new Record() {
    Name = "12345"
  });
  this.Records.Add(new Record() {
    Name = "54321"
  });
  }
}

public class Record : NotifyPropertyChanged {

private string _name;
public string Name {
    get => this._name;
    set {
      this._name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Name));
    }
  }
}

public abstract class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public void OnPropertyChanged(string property) {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
  }
}


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).Records[0].Name = "AAAAA";
}
```

Comment: А если так попробовать `<ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" ...`?

Comment: P. S. _В WPF много WTF (c)_

Answer (score 1):

Логика в этом поведении как раз есть.

Если `ComboBox` редактируемый, значение, показываемое в поле редактирования не имеет смысла автоматически синхронизировать с выбранным элементом, ведь юзер мог вбить туда своё значение. А затирать введённое юзером значение не комильфо.

Идея «затирать значение только если юзер его ещё не модифицировал» совсем плоха.

---

Что нужно делать? Смотря от того, чего вы хотите добиться. Нужно ли вам, чтобы комбобокс был редактируемым? Тогда текущее поведение выглядит правильно, с учётом возможности редактирования.

Если вы хотите в некоторых случаях затирать значение, которое установалено пользователем, то напишите логику, которая будет обновлять поле `Text`.

По сути, редактируемый и нередактируемый комбобоксы — это очень разные контролы, и поведение у них тоже разное.